# Geometry in $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$, lines and points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Let $L=u+\operatorname{span}\{v\}$ be a line in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $w \in \mathbb{R} ^{n}$ be any point.
>
> Define a function $f\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f\left( t\right) =\left\| w-\left( u+tv\right) \right\|$. Show that there exists $t^{*} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ decreases on $( -\infty ,t^{\ast }]$ and increases on $[t^{\ast}, \infty)$. Also show that $t^{*}$ that you found satisfies  $\langle w-\left( u+t^{\ast }v\right) ,v \rangle = 0$.

So in order to find who is $t^{*}$, I started by solving the last equation and got that $t^{*} = \dfrac{ \langle w-u, v\rangle }{\langle u , v\rangle }$, which immediately reminded me the orthogonal projection. Now I'm stuck on how to prove increasing an decreasing of $f$ and can't figure out how to do it.
would be glad for some help

Comment: Did you draw in $\Bbb R^2$, giving particular values ​​to $w, u, v$? As you know, the secret of the study of linear algebra consists in establishing the fruitful link between elementary geometry and linear algebra. If you do, everything becomes clear. If you don't, you are like a blind man with powerful tools.

Comment: @StephaneJaouen Yes, indeed I chose these points, draw it in my papers, gave values and calculated everything and it worked out, but what I can't see is how I prove that this $t^{*}$ is an extreme point

Comment: $f(t)=\sqrt{\langle w-\left( u+tv\right),w-(u+tv)\rangle}$ by definition. Start by developing $\langle w-\left( u+tv\right),w-(u+tv)\rangle$

Comment: @StephaneJaouen Ok, Ideveloped it as much as I could, found the derivative and by comparison to $0$ I found that it is my point, now you suggest to use the derivative to show it?

Comment: You have $t^{*}\in\mathbb R^n$. Should that be $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Take the shortest distance from $w$ to the line. A segment from $w$ to the line will be perpendicular to the line and will intersect it at $u+t^{*}v$ and the inner product of zero will follow immediately. If you start at $-\infty$ then the distance starts large and reaches a minimum at $t^{*}$. As you continue to $\infty$ it increases again.

Comment: Typo in the denominator of $t^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^+, t\mapsto \langle w-\left( u+tv\right),w-(u+tv)\rangle$
$$\forall t \in \Bbb R,g(t)=\langle v,v\rangle t^2-2 \langle v,w-u\rangle t +\langle w-u,w-u\rangle$$
$g(t)=at^2+bt+c$, with $a=\langle v,v\rangle, b=-2 \langle v,w-u\rangle$ and $c=\langle w-u,w-u\rangle$.

So $g $  decreases on $(-\infty,t^∗]$ and increases on $[t^∗,+\infty)$, with $t^*=-\frac{b}{2a}$.

And the same for $f$.

For the example illustration below, $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb C, u=-4-6i, v=1+2i, w=2-4i, g(t)=|w-(u+tv)|^2=5(t^2-4t+8)$

[image]
[image]

Comment: Forgive me, but I really can't see how can you say directly that $g$ increases or decreases in this intervals and why the same goes for f, when the result is applied for $f^{2}$

Comment: yw, g is a polynomial function of t of degree 2; its curve is a parabola with minimum $-\frac{b}{2a}$, isn't it?

Comment: @PythonAddict $f$ is always positive, so $f^2$ increases and decreases exactly when $f$ does.

Comment: Yes, I see it now

Comment: $f'(t)=\frac{g'(t)}{2\sqrt{g(t)}}$